# fail2ban regular to find 403 request in nginx

Tags: regex, linux, nginx, fail2ban

I want to find the 403 requests and ban them,here is my log format

```
112.253.6.182 - - [08/Sep/2014:17:42:56 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 579 "baidu" "Mozilla/4.0" 50.117.86.72
106.37.177.251 - - [08/Sep/2014:17:42:56 -0400] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 576 "baidu" "Mozilla/4.0" 204.44.65.173
190.254.173.14 - - [08/Sep/2014:17:42:56 -0400] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 576 "baidu" "Mozilla/4.0" 204.44.65.173
41.222.196.37 - - [08/Sep/2014:17:42:56 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 579 "baidu" "Mozilla/4.0" 50.117.86.72
```

and my failreg is:

```
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*.php.*\ 403\ .*$
```

ignoreregex =

but when I test it using fail2ban-regex command , it returns below

```
Failregex: 32 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [32] ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*.php.*\ 403\ .*$
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [3266] Day/MONTH/Year:Hour:Minute:Second
`-

Lines: 3266 lines, 0 ignored, 32 matched, 3234 missed
Missed line(s): too many to print.  Use --print-all-missed to print all 3234 lines
```

could you help me to make a regex to match 403 requests and print the ip out . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your example log entrys are 403s for `/`, and 404s for `/index.php`, whereas your regex tries to match *php* extension and 403 code. There's no wonder you have no match.

So if your interest is only a 403 error entry regardless of path, this should work.

```
^<HOST> .* "(GET|POST) [^"]+" 403
```

To debug your regular expression you can use [this snippet](http://regex101.com/r/iY5hU9/1). Note that `<HOST>` is preprocessed to `(?:::f{4,6}:)?(?P<host>\S+)` by *fail2ban*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help .The online regex tester is awesome .

Answer (score 0):

As per @saaj's answer, while the four lines of log don't have a match, it is obvious from the test results on the full log that there were 32 matches. That said, the new pattern (excluding the php extension) does catch more 403s, obviously.

A simpler pattern to match would be: `^<HOST> .* 403`

This can be tested from the command line with:

`fail2ban-regex '112.253.6.182 - - [08/Sep/2014:17:42:56 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 579 "baidu" "Mozilla/4.0" 50.117.86.72' '^<HOST> .* 403'`

for a positive result, and

`fail2ban-regex '106.37.177.251 - - [08/Sep/2014:17:42:56 -0400] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 576 "baidu" "Mozilla/4.0" 204.44.65.173' '^<HOST> .* 403'`

for a negative result.