# fail2ban scan for 403 in nginx access logs

Tags: regex, nginx, fail2ban

I have setup some specific rules on nginx, blocking some urls and some extensions (aspx, sh, jsp, etc..).
I have also enable a custom access log file only for 403|429|410 errors, so that in only 1 place i can have all my access denied log.

My goal is to have fail2ban read this log and for every GET/POST that ends in a 403 error, IP should be banned.

1) nginx.conf will be logging the custom error log file like this:

> log_format limit '$time_local - $remote_addr "$request" $status';

and this is a log entry:

```
03/Jan/2017:15:53:01 +0100 - 1.2.3.4 "GET /aaa.jsp HTTP/1.1" 403
```

2) i have a fail2ban filter like this (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25847153))

```
^<HOST> .* "(GET|POST) [^"]+" 403
```

3) i have tried with fail2ban-regex

> fail2ban-regex /var/log/nginx/access-live-limitbot-website.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-403.conf

and this is the output

```html
Results
=======

Failregex: 0 total

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [1] Day/MONTH/Year:Hour:Minute:Second
`-

Lines: 2 lines, 0 ignored, 0 matched, 2 missed
|- Missed line(s):
|  217.19.158.242 "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 403
|  03/Jan/2017:15:53:01 +0100 - 217.19.158.242 "GET /aaa.jsp HTTP/1.1" 403
`-
```

and i will never get the entry matching the error code.

Will someone please help me with the regex based on my custom log?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

Fail2ban is picky about the date format. Also, for ease of matching, I suggest reordering the items in the log.

For date format, see documentation here:

- https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8

> In order for a log line to match your failregex, it actually has to match in two parts: the beginning of the line has to match a timestamp pattern or regex, and the remainder of the line has to match your failregex. If the failregex is anchored with a leading ^, then the anchor refers to the start of the remainder of the line, after the timestamp and intervening whitespace.
>
> The pattern or regex to match the time stamp is currently not documented, and not available for users to read or set. See Debian bug #491253. This is a problem if your log has a timestamp format that fail2ban doesn't expect, since it will then fail to match any lines. Because of this, you should test any new failregex against a sample log line, as in the examples below, to be sure that it will match. If fail2ban doesn't recognize your log timestamp, then you have two options: either reconfigure your daemon to log with a timestamp in a more common format, such as in the example log line above; or file a bug report asking to have your timestamp format included.

For the reorder, something like datetime - status - host (- other stuff), would help create a simple pattern such as  403.

Therefore your log should look like:

`03-01-2017 15:53:01 403 1.2.3.4 "GET /aaa.jsp HTTP/1.1"`

and your pattern can be

`403 <HOST>`

**You can run this from the command line to validate** as:

`fail2ban-regex '03-01-2017 15:53:01 403 1.2.3.4 "GET /aaa.jsp HTTP/1.1"' '403 <HOST>'`

Which produces the output:

```
Running tests
=============

Use regex line : 403 <HOST>
Use single line: 03-01-2017 15:53:01 403 1.2.3.4 "GET /aaa.jsp HTTP...

Matched time template Day-Month-Year Hour:Minute:Second
Got time using template Day-Month-Year Hour:Minute:Second

Results
=======

Failregex: 1 total
|- #) [# of hits] regular expression
|  1) [1] 403 <HOST>
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Summary
=======

Addresses found:
[1]
    1.2.3.4 (Tue Jan 03 15:53:01 2017)

Date template hits:
2 hit(s): Day-Month-Year Hour:Minute:Second

Success, the total number of match is 1
```